# MQTT broker inside the Azure Website

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, mqtt, azure-node-sdk

I have a Azure website that developed using the ASP.Net WebApi2 running in a Standard plan. I was wondering if its possible to host a MQTT broker in the same website so that I don't have to pay anything extra to have this running in azure.

I see that there are some opensource product like [Mosca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mosca) which is a Nodejs application. So I was wondering if anyone has tried to host a nodejs application on the same website as my webAPI application.

alternatively any one has any other way to have a MQTT broker running alongside my WebAPI portal.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to host your second site in the same website. Just create a new website but when you're choosing the App Service Plan for the site select your pre-existing Standard plan.

You can add as many sites as you like* for free on that plan since they'll all be running on the same VM.

*though at some point you'll start running up against the memory and cpu limits of the VM

Comment: Thanks, but what if my website is in the basic or free tier, in that case would it be possible to add a NodeJs part to co exist with the WebAPI?